# How to use checkboxes to get data

Tags: vba, checkbox, ms-access-2007

I have a forum called FrmAgent. which is grabbing the data from the table named "Agent". In this table there is a column named "Agent Name". Under this cloumn there are 5 names "Chris" "Nikita" "Noe" "Jennifer" and "Diane". On the forum i have check boxes with these names next to a checkbox. all different checkboxes of course. What i need to do is be able to run my query that will grab data from the table "Agent" from the forum that has each checkbox marked.

Example if i have check box marked for Chris and Diane i need to grab all there data from the table "Agent". If just one of them is marked just grab that persons data.

Does this make sense? Can you guys please help me i am very new to vba and access. examples and coding would help out tremendously. Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

On the assumption you have a "Submit" or "Filter" command button, you could use code like the following:

```
Dim strFilter  As String
Dim i          As Integer
strFilter = ""
If Me.chkbox1.Value = true Then
    strFilter = "([Agent Name] = '" & Me.Name1Value & "' AND "
End IF
If Me.chkbox2.Value = true Then
    strFilter = strFilter  & "([Agent Name] = '" & Me.Name2Value & "' AND "
End IF
<<<<REPEAT AS MANY TIMES AS NEEDED>>>
If right(strFilter, 4) = "AND " Then
    i = len(strFilter)
    Strfilter = left(strFilter, i - 4)
Me.Filter = strFilter
Me.FilterOn = True
Me.Requery
i = Me.Recordset.RecordCount
If i = 0 Then
     MsgBox "There are no records selected", vbOKOnly, "No Records”
‘You could delete the filter & Requery if you want.
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Wayne G. Dunn Thank you for the reply. i keep getting an error that says misused word of Me. What can i do to fix this?

Comment: "Me" refers to the form in which this code is located.  It sounds like you placed the code NOT in your form. Where is the code located? Please show the entire code including subroutine name. Also, please tell me the EXACT line of code where you get the error. Also, does your Form contain a subform?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that i used. I made a module and a macro to run in. i attached a button on the form to connect the two together. i get the error at the very first me statement. There are no subforms. Thank you again for the help.
Option Compare Database

Function YoMomma()

```
Dim strFilter  As String
Dim i          As Integer
    strFilter = ""
        If Me.Chris.Value = True Then
            strFilter = "([Agent Name] = '" & Me.Chris & "' AND "
        End If
        If Me.Diane.Value = True Then
             strFilter = strFilter & "([Agent Name] = '" & Me.Diane & "' AND "
        End If
         If Me.Noe.Value = True Then
            strFilter = "([Agent Name] = '" & Me.Noe & "' AND "
        End If
        If Me.Jennifer.Value = True Then
             strFilter = strFilter & "([Agent Name] = '" & Me.Jennifer & "' AND "
        End If
         If Me.Nikita.Value = True Then
            strFilter = "([Agent Name] = '" & Me.Nikita & "' AND "
        End If
        'REPEAT AS MANY TIMES AS NEEDED
         If Right(strFilter, 4) = "AND " Then
            i = Len(strFilter)
            strFilter = Left(strFilter, i - 4)
            Me.Filter = strFilter
            Me.FilterOn = True
            Me.Requery
            i = Me.Recordset.RecordCount
        If i = 0 Then
             MsgBox "There are no records selected", vbOKOnly, "No Records”"
            'You could delete the filter & Requery if you want.
        End If
```

End If
End Function